# Javascript pop up box

Tags: javascript, popup

I created a pop up box on my site.

I added the pop up box to 3 separate buttons and for some reason the pop up will only work for the first button.

I deleted the id tag: id="myBtn" on the first button and then the pop up worked on my second button but still wouldn't work on my third button

On the pop up box, I would also like to have a link to direct the user to the contact form and when the user clicks on the link the pop up window should close.

here is the javascript code:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Here is the html code:

```
<footer class="panel-footer"><div class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-default"><button id="myBtn">Sign up now</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<span class="close">×</span>
<h2><img src="http://localhost:8383/homepage/img/logo.png" style="width:250px"></h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Please contact us via the <a href="#">contact form</a> as our sign up system is currently under construction</p>
<p>Sorry for any inconvenience &nbsp; :) </p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<h3 align="center">SUPP Software LTD.</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div></footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have same ID on all buttons. `document.getElementById` always returns only one element. ID has to be unique. Change it to the class and bind event to every element returned by `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Thanks everyone,

I am having a hard time implementing this as I am new to javascript if anyone could help me about a little bit

Answer (score 0):

If you're giving all your buttons an id of `myBtn` then it would make sense that it fails because you are setting `btn = document.getElementById('myBtn')` which is finding the first element with an id of `myBtn`. Do what Eduard said 1. use a class since the elements are not unique and 2. retrieve all the elements instead of just one using `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 0):

Example 1 :

with Class name,

```html
   <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="b">Button1</button>
        <button class="b">Button2</button>
        <button class="b">Button3</button>
        <script>
             var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("b")[0];
             btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
                 alert("Button1");
             })
              var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("b")[1];
             btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
                 alert("Button2");
             })
              var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("b")[2];
             btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
                 alert("Button3");
             })
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Example 2 :

with Id,

```html
   <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn1">Button1</button>
        <button id="btn2">Button2</button>
        <button id="btn3">Button3</button>
        <script>
             var btn = document.getElementById("btn1");
             btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
                 alert("Button1");
             })
              var btn = document.getElementById("btn2");
             btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
                 alert("Button2");
             })
              var btn = document.getElementById("btn3");
             btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
                 alert("Button3");
             })
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```